# SVG-edit link won't open in new window

Tags: javascript, svg

I have created a link in SVG Edit and I want this link to open in a new window. I googled if this was possible which it apparently is by adding this code:

xlink:show="new"

I click SVG source and add it where the page tells me to add it, but the code won´t stay and if I open the SVG source again, the code is gone.

What am I doing wrong? Can I open a link in SVG edit in a new window and how?

Answer (score 1):

SVG Edit has a sanitizer which removes attributes and elements it does not understand. These are listed in the file `sanitize.js`.

If you are adding this to the anchor `a` element you can this attribute to line 29 of sanitize.js:

```
"a": ["xlink:show", "class", "clip-path", [...]],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `target="_blank"` instead I think it's more widely supported than xlink:show.